# Passing Variable between JavaScript click handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to pass variable in javaScript click handlers.

I have assigned `var condition_selction = ($(this).val());` in `.change(function)`. How I can get the value of this variable in the second click handle which is  `$( "#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled" ).click(function() {`.

How I pass variable between these two functions.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
        /*get the parent node of the radio and then hide only its siblings*/
        $(this).parent('label').siblings().toggle();
        if ($('.sign-condition').is(':checked')) {
            var condition_selction = ($(this).val());
        }
        if ($('.sign-reason').is(':checked')) {
            var reason_selction = ($(this).val());
        }
        //Check that both select fields have a value
        if (condition_selction != null && reason_selction != null) {
            $("#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-disabled").hide();
            $("#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled").show();
        } else {
            $("#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-disabled").show();
            $("#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled").hide();
        }
    });

    $( "#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled" ).click(function() {



            var process_signs_scrap_condition = condition_selction;


            var process_signs_scrap_reason = reason_selction


            // Open the timer modal
            $('#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: What about global variable or scope of variable same for both of two function?

Answer (score 1):

Declare both var globally, so you can access them in both functions

```
var condition_selction; // like this
var reason_selction;

$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    /*get the parent node of the radio and then hide only its siblings*/
    $(this).parent('label').siblings().toggle();
    if ($('.sign-condition').is(':checked')) {
        condition_selction = ($(this).val()); // removed declaration 
    }
    if ($('.sign-reason').is(':checked')) {
        reason_selction = ($(this).val());
    }
    //Check that both select fields have a value
    if (condition_selction != null && reason_selction != null) {
        $("#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-disabled").hide();
        $("#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled").show();
    } else {
        $("#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-disabled").show();
        $("#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled").hide();
    }
});

$( "#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled" ).click(function() {



        var process_signs_scrap_condition = condition_selction;


        var process_signs_scrap_reason = reason_selction


        // Open the timer modal
        $('#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-modal').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value to a data attribute on the button and then on the onclick of the button access the data attribute and its good to go. I have modified some of your code to get a sample version going.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
        if ($('.sign-condition').is(':checked')) {
            var condition_selction = $(this).val();
            $("#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled").attr('data-value', condition_selction );
        }
   })

    $( "#process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled" ).click(function() {
            var  condition_selction = $(this).attr('data-value');
           console.log("The value of the checkbox is "  + condition_selction);
            })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="sign-condition" value="sign condition" /> click me first
</label>
<hr/>
<button type="button" data-value="" id="process-signs-scrap-scrapped-button-enabled">click me last</button>
```